# removing outliers in skewed data for xgboost

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, outliers, boosting

i have a couple of columns in my data which are postively skewed. they are non-normal from the hist plots. plotting a qq plot further cinfirms this. i should remove outliers from my data for xgboost. however what method should i use to remove outliers from postively skewed dataset.[image]

[image]

i have considered log transform and cube root to transform but this still leaves it skewed (note i do have some negative values which are expected)

Comment: i have seen that and i understand that, but then why are there differences on this? like the article i posted above

Comment: thx, i have changed the question now.

Comment: This question was not answered but the later thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466662/yeo-johnson-does-not-increase-normality contains relevant material.